# Executing javascript in an an AJAX response - Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using Codigniter to redo a website.  I have the following controller code:

```
public function get_topics()
{          
    $topic = $this->input->post('input_data');
    $topics = $this->firstcoast_model->get_topics_like($topic); 
    foreach ($topics as $val) {
        echo "<pre id = \"pre_" . $val['id'] . "\">";
        echo $val['formula'];
        echo "<br />";

        // generate a unique javascript file.
        $f = "file_" . $val['id'] . ".js";

        if (!file_exists($f));
        {
            $file = fopen($f,"w");
            $js = "\$(\"#button_" . $val['id'] . "\").click(function(){\$(\"#pre_" . $val['id'] . "\").hide();});"; 
            fwrite($file,$js);
            fclose($file);
         }

         echo "<script src=\"file_" . $val['id'] . ".js\"></script>";
         echo "<button id=\"button_" . $val['id'] . "\">Hide</button>";
         echo "</pre>";
     } 
 }
```

The basic idea to make an AJAX call to the function to retrieve a list of formulas. 
The purpose of the javascript is to be able to hide any of the formulas by
hiding the <`pre`> <`/pre`> tag that surrounds them  The js file (i.e. file_1.js) I generate looks like:

```
$("#button_1").click(function(){$("#pre_1").hide();});
```

and the button code is:

```
<button id="button_1">Hide</button>
```

The problem is that it doesn't work. The files get generated, but clicking on the "Hide"
button does nothing.  The puzzling part is that the exact same code works on the original website where I just make an AJAX call to a PHP file that generates the same code.

Any ideas what could be going on here?

Edit:

On my old website I used:

```
         $query = "SELECT * FROM topics WHERE term LIKE '%" . $term . "%'";
         $result = mysql_query($query);

        while ($val = mysql_fetch_array($result))
         { 
          echo "<pre id = \"pre_" . $val['id'] . "\">";
          etc.
          etc.
         }
```

and everything works fine.  If I now put the results of the while loop into to an array and then do a foreach loop on that, the results are very intermittent. I'm wondering if the foreach loop is the problem.

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '#button_1', function(){$("#pre_1").hide();});`

Comment: Tried that and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can return list buttons in json response

```
public function get_topics()
{          
    $topic = $this->input->post('input_data');
    $topics = $this->firstcoast_model->get_topics_like($topic);         
    $response = array('buttons' => $topics);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode( $arr );
}
```

so client can parse which button element to be hide.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('somEL').on('submit', function() { // This event fires when a somEl loaded          
      $.ajax({
          url: 'url to getTopics() controller',
          type : "POST",
          data: 'input_data=' + $(this).val(), // change this based on your input name
          dataType: 'json', // Choosing a JSON datatype
          success: function(data) 
          {
              for (var btn in data.buttons) {
                  $(btn).hide();
              }
          }
      });
      return false; // prevent page from refreshing 
  });
});
</script>
```